# Mostrar datos de una caja de texto en Java Script

Tags: javascript, procesamiento-de-texto

¡Hola! Soy nueva en JS, estoy aprendiendo con mucha información que hay internet. Sin embargo, no logro encontrar una manera de capturar los datos de una caja de texto.

Digamos que quiero poner una opcion para que el usuario ingrese su nombre en una caja de texto, y una vez que lo ingrese y dé clic al boton que dice continuar, la pantalla deberia decirle: ¡Hola (el nombre que ingreso)!

Sé que es algo muy basico, pero no encuentro informacion al respecto (no de la manera en la que la busco, jaja), y les agradeceria mucho su ayuda!

Comment: Pues esa caja de texto puede ser un <textarea> o un <input type="text">. Despues en js seleccionas el boton que activa el msj y le agregas un evento "onclick" y que ese evento ejecute una funcion que te muestre el mensaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías ejecutar un evento click al presionar el botón continuar, puedes agregarle un `id` a tu campo de texto para identificarlo y tomar el valor del campo desde el JavaScript, un ejemplo seria este:

```js
function btnContinue() {
  var input=document.getElementById('inputName');
  if(input.value!='') {
    alert('¡Hola '+input.value+'!');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputName">
<button type="button" onclick="btnContinue()">Continuar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Has hecho muy feliz a una novata hoy

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda solucionar el problema  no todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas si no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. A la pregunta le hace falta mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer.

Comment: De nada @Balas :)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".boton-enviar");
btn.addEventListener("click",mostrarNombre);

function mostrarNombre(){
const nombre = document.querySelector(".boton-nombre").value;

//Aca puedes mostrarlo en un alerta o en cualquier parte del dom, para el ejemplo usaré un alert
alert(`¡Hola ${nombre}!`);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="boton-nombre">
<input type="submit" class="boton-enviar">
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda solucionar el problema  no todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas si no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. A la pregunta le hace falta mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer.